# ESP32 cannot program on Eclipse with Arduino Plug-in

Tags: eclipse, arduino, esp32

I am trying to use the Arduino plug-on for Eclipse to program an ESP32 development module.

I am able to successfully build the project but I am unable to program the target (Launch in 'Run' mode). I get the following error:

```
usage: esptool write_flash [-h] [--flash_freq {keep,40m,26m,20m,80m}]
                           [--flash_mode {keep,qio,qout,dio,dout}]
                           [--flash_size FLASH_SIZE]
                           [--spi-connection SPI_CONNECTION] [--no-progress]
                           [--verify] [--compress | --no-compress]
                           <address> <filename> [<address> <filename> ...]
esptool write_flash: error: argument <address> <filename>: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './ESP32_Test.partitions.bin'
```

I am compiling the "LEDC Software Fade" example code that is provided with the Arduino IDE for the ESP32. The code compiles successfully in the ARDUINO IDE and I am able to program is with the ARDUINO IDE, but NOT with ECLIPSE.

**Here is my setup:**

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800
OS: Windows 7, v.6.1, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_121

From the marketplace I installed the Eclipse C++ IDE for Arduino 3.0

In the Arduino Preferences I specified the package source for the ESP32 platform: https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json

I have set up an Ardiuno target with Board type: ESP32 Dev Model. The
rest of the taget settings is exactly the same as specified in the Arduino IDE.

What am I missing here?

Comment: UPDATE:

I have found that in the Arduino IDE, the followling tool is called:

`\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\esp32\\hardware\\esp32\\1.0.0/tools/gen_esp32part.exe"`

whereas this is never called in Eclipse with the C++ Arduino Plugin. I have downloaded the exact same toolchain from `https://dl.espressif.com/dl/package_esp32_index.json` for both the Arduino IDE and Eclipse.

I have no idea how to add this in Eclipse. It seems like it defined the partitions.

Comment: use Sloeber Arduino Eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found a workaround by modifying the next line in `.arduinocdt\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\platform.txt`:

```
\#\# Combine gc-sections, archives, and objects
recipe.c.combine.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.elf.cmd}" {compiler.c.elf.flags} {compiler.c.elf.extra_flags} -Wl,--start-group {object_files} "{archive_file_path}" {compiler.c.elf.libs} -Wl,--end-group -Wl,-EL -o "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf" && {tools.gen_esp32part.cmd.windows} -q "{runtime.platform.path}/tools/partitions/{build.partitions}.csv" "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.partitions.bin"
```